# How to show the data of Core Data in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am getting the response from JSON and stored that data by using Core Data. I want to show the data always in a `UITableView`. Can you suggest me how to display data in a `UITableView`?

This is the code I'm using.

```
    NSManagedObject * newEntry =[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"albumName"] forKey:@"albumName"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"coverPhotoURL"] forKey:@"coverPhotoURL"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];

    NSLog(@"Log %@", newEntry);

    NSError * error = nil;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"CANNOT SAVE: %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"SUCCES, go check the sqlite file");
    }
}


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GetAlbums"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError* error;    
NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"Fetch Records %@",fetchedRecords);
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `UITableViewController`s at all?

Comment: ya i know  tableView

Comment: You already have your array of fetched records, just show them in your table view then. - is your question around how to extract the element from the array?

Comment: i wrote this only     [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: have you read this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/

Comment: or [RTFM](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if, as suggested by walle84, you can implement the methods of `UITableViewDelegate` to display data in your table view, the right way is to use a `UITableView` in combination with [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The latter is, as written in the doc, used

> to **efficiently** manage the results returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a UITableView object.

I put the emphasis on efficiently since it provides a lot of pros. For example, it allows lazy loading of data, it allows to track changes for a specific entity (implementing `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`), etc.

Where to start? There are a lot of tuts. Just google them and you will find a good point to start.

- [Core Data From Scratch](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-21681)
- [How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You use below methods of table view so show your data.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return  [self.arrayOfyourData count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    //you could use default cell or ur own custom cell.
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Now here you could pare your self.arrayOfyourData to fetch and populate your cell.

    return cell;
}
```